# Is std::vector good for frequent resizing?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, resize

I am creating a game where i have small "particles". Their number is changing very frequently (every few seconds) and i'm wondering what is the best way to store them. Is `std::vector` or `std::deque` better for this?

Is it okay to reserve space (in that container) that will never get used (I have upper limit)?

Comment: Give us some more information about the usage.

Comment: if you only erase the last item of a vector, it's a usually reasonably fast. Can you give a maximum number of particles?

Comment: Make your code modular so that it's easy to swap out container types and *profile*.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Maximum number will be normally about 100 - 150 so i will use vector and reserve space for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of removing a particle you can just replace it with the other one in a vector if order does not matter (and I think it does not)

```
std::vector<Particle> particles;
```

when you remove a particle at index `i` - just fill the empty space with the last one:

```
particles[i] = particles.back();
particles.pop_back();
```

You can make it even faster if using vector of pointers.

Comment: I'm curious: why are you using resize(..) instead of pop_back()? Is there a downside of pop_back()?

Comment: @stefan: yeah, pop_back is better

Comment: @stefan This is still odd. Why would you use assignment instead of `swap`?

Comment: I don't think it would be faster with a vector of pointers. With a vector of pointers, he will lose the fact that memory is contiguous. It really depends on what the particles actually are and what kind of computation will be involved.

Comment: @Adrien: that actually depends on the size of particle. But you have to try such optimization only if simple solution is not fast enough. And possible this optimization will be slower )

Comment: @pmr: I agree with `swap`, especially in light of C++11 and the `std::swap` automatically implemented in terms of move constructors.

Comment: @MatthieuM. :swap will actually change the last particle to one at index i. But this operation is not needed because of the pop_back() coming next line. So i think simple assignment is better in this case

Comment: @Andrew: the point is that the assignment will (necessarily) copy `particles.back()` to `particles[i]`. If `Particle` is expensive to copy but cheap to move, say for example if it contained a large vector of strings, then it would be cheaper to do the swap. If `Particle` is POD then the assignment is cheaper, because move is no cheaper than copy for POD types and `swap` requires 3 of them. So the "use a swap" people are telling you to optimize for the worst case, but since the questioner knows more about `Particle` than they do, they might not be best placed to make that determination ;-)

Comment: ... in C++11 you could write `particles[i] = std::move(particles.back())` and get the best of both worlds. Of course then your code is dependent on C++11.

Comment: @Andrew : that's way i wrote "It really depends on what the particles actually are", i was concerned about the size.

Answer (score 2):

If you reserve enough space for the vector, resize is not bad, because it doesn't need to copy the vector's content.

One the other hand, dequeue can grow more efficiently than the vectors with their capacity managed automatically, specially in large sequences, because massive reallocations are avoided.

Answer (score 2):

It really comes down to usage. If your vector is unsorted, if you are actually removing that particle, it has complexity O(n) to find it within your vector and the whole vector will be copied so the data remains contiguous. With a deque, it still takes O(n) to find, but removal is trivial. However, if you are iterating like

```
foreach (particle in particles)
{
    if(particle.update() == END_OF_LIFE)
    {
        particle.alive = false;
    }
    else
    {
        particle.draw();
    }
}
```

you can do it with no significant overhead, but to insert new particles you will either need to iterate through each particle to find the first 'dead' one you can replace (O(n)), or keep track of that information in a separate std::list.

One thing we need to know to effectively answer - do you ever need to index to a particular particle ("give me the 1000th particle in the list")? Also, do you ever look up by some ID ("find the particle with id=421932")?  If the former, vector performs that in constant time, whereas the latter would be performed in constant time by an std::unordered_set (c++ x11 version of hash_set, similar options in boost pre x11) and logn time by std::set.